# Change iframe scroll-bar position

Tags: html, css, iframe, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

In *wysihtml5* the `iframe` *scroll-bar* is displayed on the right side by default, but I need to display it on the left side to support the *Arabic view*.

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox"
  allowtransparency="true"  
  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
  style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; 
  border-color: rgb(218, 218, 231); border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; 
  clear: none; display: block; float: none; margin: 0px; outline: 0px none rgb(85, 85, 85); 
  outline-offset: 0px; padding: 6px 12px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto;
  bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: text-bottom; text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: none; border-radius: 2px; width: 1354.17px;
  height: 214px;direction:rtl;" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

I've set the `direction: rtl` but no success.

https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5
[image: Live privew]

Comment: _“I've set the direction: rtl but no success”_ - looking at the demos provided on the project page, it seems like this script constantly overwrites the inline styles for the iframe element, and it resets direction to ltr while doing so.

Comment: @CBroe I changed the script t o be rtl and when i checked the output HTML code the direction was rtl of iframe .

Comment: @CBroe I added the result image to the qoustion please check it